# Problem with using pretrained vector. Tokenizetion problem

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tokenize

I use pretrained vectors for keras model and have problem by converting words to ids. For that I use tokenizer. But get an error :

```
index 117004 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 116997
```

I suppose that the problem is that it get ids for train, but doesnt extend them for dev and test.

```
t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts(X_train_words)
vocab_size = len(t.word_index) + 1
X_train = np.array(t.texts_to_sequences(X_train_words))
t.fit_on_texts(X_dev_words)
X_dev = np.array(t.texts_to_sequences(X_dev_words))
t.fit_on_texts(X_test_words)
X_test = np.array(t.texts_to_sequences(X_test_words))
```

The problem appeares here (embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector)

```
for word, i in t.word_index.items():
embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
if embedding_vector is not None:
    embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What I do wrong, that I get here this error: "index 117004 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 116997 " in this line: embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

Comment: "I suppose that the problem is that it get ids for train, but doesnt extend them for dev and test." Yes you are right, you should just ignore all words, which are not in the vocabulary.